# Iterator should return strings, not list error with csv.reader

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

This code shows the error in the title.. Help me out plz.I wrote the following code to write to a csv file reading the input from another file but this shows the error.When i change "r" to "rb" then it shows "iterator should return byte" error.

error->Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abhirav.sati/Downloads/salesdata.py", line 34, in 
    csv_reader(csvReader,path)
  File "C:/Users/abhirav.sati/Downloads/salesdata.py", line 11, in csv_reader
    for row in read:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not list (did you open the file in text mode?)

```
import csv
def csv_reader(fileobj,path):
    read=csv.reader(fileobj,delimiter=',')
    with open(path, "wt") as csv_file:
        write=csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        i=1
        for row in read:
            if(i==1):
                write.writerow(",".join(row))
                i=2
                continue
            if(row[3]=="Trade"):
                continue
            else:
                if(row[6]==NULL):
                    r=[row[0],row[0],"A,",row[8],row[9],row[0]]
                    #r=row[0]+row[0]+"A,"+row[8]+row[9]+row[0]
                    write.writerow(r)
                else:
                    r=[row[0],row[0],"B,",row[6],row[7],row[0]]
                    #r=row[0]+row[0]+"A,"+row[8]+row[9]+row[0]
                    write.writerow(r)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path="sales.csv"
    csv_path = "FlowEdge-TRTH-Time_Sales.csv"
    f_obj  = open(csv_path, "r")
    data=csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in f_obj), delimiter=",")
    csv_reader(data,path)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to correct the indentation and add the complete traceback of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is applying `csv.reader` on *another* `csv.reader` object. Look carefully at your `__main__` and `csv_reader` function to make sure you understand why this is the case.

A better solution is to use `with open...` with multiple files:

```
with open(path, 'wt') as f1, open('csv_path', 'r') as f2:
    write = csv.writer(f1, delimiter=',')
    read = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: oh sorry for that.but on marking line 3 "read=csv.reader......" as comment and updating in line 7th as "for row in fileobj" it shows the error -->" for row in fileobj:
  File "E:\flowedge material\salesdata.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    data=csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in f_obj), delimiter=",")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: @abhihacker02, Sorry, comments aren't a good place to write code. If you want to test my solution, feel free to do so and update your question if necessary.